# Alternative concatenation of tensors

Tags: pytorch, concatenation, tensor

I have 2 tensors of shape [2, 1, 9] and [2, 1, 3]. I'd like to concatenate across the 3rd dimension alternatively (once every 4).

For example:

```
a = [[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]],[[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]]]
b = [[[10, 20, 30]], [[1, 2, 3]]]
result = [[[1,2,3,10,4,5,6,20,7,8,9,30]],[[11,12,13,1,14,15,16,2,17,18,19,3]]]
```

How can I do this in pytorch?

Comment: Not an ideal solution, but one possibility is: `torch.concat([a.reshape((2, 1, 3, 3)), b.reshape(2, 1, 3, 1)], axis=-1).reshape((2, 1, -1))`

Comment: Works for me. Please post this as an answer so that I can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```py
torch.concat([a.reshape((2, 1, 3, 3)), b.reshape(2, 1, 3, 1)], axis=-1).reshape((2, 1, -1))
```

There's probably a smarter way to do this, but hey, it works.